# Is there any way to get row number for each search result in map stage?

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I have 1 map/reduce script with input data is a saved search with > 100k results. I need to get the index of each result when running the map stage (row number of search results). Can someone please give me an idea?

Answer (score 2):

From the Help Center entry for `mapContext.key`:
If the input type is a result set, the key is the internal ID of the result.
**If the search result has no internal ID, the key is the index of the search result**.

When your search result has an internal ID, add Formula (Numeric) with formula = `rownum` to your result columns (http://www.netsuiterp.com/2019/01/display-row-numbers-in-saved-search.html).

Comment: You could add grouping to every column to ensure the result has no internal id.

Comment: And sort by the rownum formula column in the second scenario

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you need. The third parameter of reduce is index and the second of map also:

```
reduce((accumulator, currentValue, index) => { ... } )
map(function callbackFn(element, index) { ... })
```

Comment: The question is referring to a NetSuite script context type known as Map/Reduce; not the array functions. Otherwise, very helpful